Dual Taylor Polynomial
I was asked to find the Taylor Polynomial of $f(x)=cos(sin(x))$ of degree 4 (the point is 0).
In the answer provided by the text book, they found first the polynomial of $cos(x)$
$cos(sin(x))= 1-\frac{sin^2(x)}{2!}+\frac{sin^4(x)}{4!}+Remainder(sin^5(x))$
Then they found the 4th degree polynomial of $sin(x)$:
$sin(x)= x-\frac{x^3}{6}$
and finally assembled:
$cos(sin(x))=1-\frac{(x-\frac{x^3}{6})^2}{2}+\frac{(x-\frac{x^3}{6})^4}{24}+Remainder(x^{13}) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{5}{24}x^4+Remainder(x^5)$
why is the remainder in the final step is now $x^{13}$? Additionally if they replaced $sin(x)$ polynomial with $x$ then where did $\frac{5}{24}$ come from?
Could someone clarify the final steps made?

It is unclear what is meant with "remainder $(x^{13})$", it doesn't seem to be true. We can try to compute the things they could have meant:
$$\begin{align}
\cos\sin x& = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24}-\frac{37x^6}{720}+\dots  
\\
\cos(x-\frac{x^3}{6})& = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24}-\frac{31x^6}{720}+\dots  
\\
1-\frac{(\sin x)^2}{2}+\frac{(\sin x)^4}{24}& = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{20}+\dots  
\\
1-\frac{(x-\frac{x^{\large 3}}{6})^2}{2}+\frac{(x-\frac{x^{\large 3}}{6})^4}{24}& = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{24}+\dots  \tag1
\end{align}$$
where the second line expands only the sine function up to fourth order and the third line only the cosine, while the last line does both. As expected the results are all the same up to $x^4$. Interestingly they all have a different $x^6$ term. Nowhere, however, is there a gap after the $x^4$ term, only to be continued with $x^{13}$. So the claim seems to be false but without further context it remains unclear...
As for the other question: the $\frac5{24}$ clearly appears in whatever way you compute things, so where it "comes from" may then have different answers. But if you substitute the polynomials into each other like in the last line of $(1)$, then clearly the 3rd term in the lhs can only give you a $\frac1{24}x^4$, while the $(x-x^3/6)^2$ in the middle term gives a $-\frac13 x^4$ which is then multiplied by $-\frac12$ so when added to the $\frac1{24}$ you have the result $\frac1{24}+\frac16$.
